# High resolution timing in wx.Python

Tags: python, timing, wxwidgets

I'm trying to run a physics simulation (using ODE) in a wxPython application. My first attempt ran my simulation at 100Hz using a timer, however this actually ran at something closer to 60Hz. It's important that the rate of the simulation is accurate, so I wrote a small thread that slept for 0.01 seconds, and then sent a message (via wx.PostEvent) to the main UI thread that ran (and rendered) the simulation.

This completely hung the application, and from logging I can see that not all of the events that I'm sending (at 100Hz) are being processed. I presume therefore that I'm filling up the message queue and my UI grinds to a halt.

When I set my thread to run at 50Hz, all works fine. But I mean, this is 2012 and I've got eight cores running at some absurd number of gigahertz or whatever. It doesn't seem to me that an accurate 100Hz is asking all that much. It only has to be accurate in the long run, some jitter (let's say 10%) is perfectly fine.

Any ideas? Here's my thread code by the way

```
def TimerThreadFunction(self):
    while self.ContinueTimer:
        time.sleep(0.01)
        wx.PostEvent(self.frame, TickEvent())
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's only a realtime simulation you can adjust the sleep seconds for every step by using the total simulation time:

```
import time

def sim_step():
    import random
    for i in xrange(random.randint(1000, 10000)):
        pass

start = time.time()
sim_time = 0
while True:
    sim_step()
    sim_time += 1
    to_sleep = max(0, sim_time*0.001 - (time.time() - start))
    time.sleep( to_sleep )
    if sim_time % 1000 == 0:
        print sim_time, time.time()
```

Comment: But the real problem is the fact that I can't get my messages sent at even close to 100Hz, which seems absurd. Once I get that going I can try your approach to keep my simulated time and real time in sync.